# Display data of Laravel Notification in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

i am implementing laravel notification now. The notification were stored in notifications table. I trying to get the data inside the data column and display in blade but failed.

This is my controller

```
public function notification_list(){
    $notifications = auth()->user()->notifications()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

    return view('users.notification.index')->with('notifications',$notifications);
}
```

This will return notification collection. But i can't get the data such as message and etc. how can i extract the "data" and convert into array?

[image]

Comment: What does your $notifications variable prints.??

Comment: You can use toArray() method to convert to Array.

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi yes it worked now, thanks for you helps.

Comment: I have added as answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toArray()` method to convert collection to Array.

Answer (score 1):

Update the code to and it worked.

```
 $notifications = auth()->user()->notifications()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$notifications= DB::table('notifications')->get();
```

if you need join with users table:

```
 $notifications= DB::table('notifications')->leftJoin('users', 'notifications.user_id','users.id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

first, u must use the DB at the top make use of the DB; class 
 to   Retrieve data from database table

```
    public function notification_list()
    {

      $notifications= DB::table('notifications')->all();

    return view('users.notification.index' , compact("notifications"));

    }
```